# Get and Set the position in Process.StandardOutput

Tags: c#, cmd, process

See as an example I open CMD and navigate to the folder I want to get the data from then I use it to open the app with arugents with standard input(all synchronously) the code so far

```
public static Process Start(bool DoNotShowWindow = false)
    {
        ProcessStartInfo cmdStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
        {
            FileName = "cmd.exe",
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            RedirectStandardError = true,
            RedirectStandardInput = true,
            UseShellExecute = false,
            CreateNoWindow = DoNotShowWindow
        };

        Process cmdProcess = new Process
        {
            StartInfo = cmdStartInfo,
            EnableRaisingEvents = true
        };

        return cmdProcess;
    }
    //in other method
    Process cli = InteractWithConsoleApp.Start();
        cli.Start();

        cli.StandardInput.WriteLine("cd /");
        cli.StandardInput.WriteLine("cd " + path);
        cli.StandardInput.WriteLine("fantasygold-cli getbalance abc");

        Thread.Sleep(5000);
```

### Problem

Now when I use StandardOutput.Readline, it starts from the beginning and returns me everything like first two lines of copyright,empty lines and even the input which in my case, after waiting 5 secs for the result I want to read line or to the end depending the input from where I had inputted.

#### possible solution

One solution I found was to change the position but it turned out it doesn't support it and even copying to another stream reader doesn't works(the position is not by line).

Well I can use filters like check a double or for an address starts with F and has a length of 36. The problem comes when I want to get the whole JSON say for like the past transactions, for which I think using filters like '{' and then check for '}'**Caveat in this** would be bad code, which I don't want.

TLDR

So, what could be the solution to my problem here :)

Comment: Can't you start that `fantasygold-cli` directly instead of going through CMD.exe?

Comment: And what is the problem? The code you show here works, right? The parsing of what that tool sends to StandardOut is on you, there is no magic.

Comment: @rene the cli is in a subfolder wallet, hence I use CMD. The problem is I have to parse the data like check if its a double for getting the balance but the real problem may occur when I start checking past transactions which **may contain multiple '{' ,'}' or '[', ']'** making it hard to parse **and** the position of standard output is not to where the output is expected **plus** there is no method to skip lines since the stream reader works this way, btw sorry for the late reply just saw the e-mail.

Comment: Share example output and what you currently have to parse that output and what you expect as result from a Parse method.

Comment: I found the answer, to open the file in subdirectory just use this `cli.StartInfo.FileName = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\SubfolderName\fantasygold-cli";`@rene thnx for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer, to open the file in subdirectory just use this `cli.StartInfo.FileName = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\SubfolderName\fantasygold-cli";`

and the arguements like getbalance as `cli.StartInfo.Arguments = "getbalance amunim"`